# Ubuntu 14 not updating or upgrading!

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, kernel, patch

I'm running into issues running

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

After I run it, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-60-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-37 linux-headers-3.16.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-38 linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-39 linux-headers-3.16.0-39-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-41 linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-43 linux-headers-3.16.0-43-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-46 linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-48 linux-headers-3.16.0-48-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-39-generic linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-39-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-48-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 318398 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic (3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-60-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-60-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic_3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic (3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic_3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.16.0-48-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.16.0-48-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic_3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic_3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I thought i might need to purge old kernels in the /boot but they are all 3.16.0-**:

```
abi-3.16.0-37-generic         initrd.img-3.16.0-60-generic
abi-3.16.0-38-generic         lost+found
abi-3.16.0-39-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.16.0-41-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.16.0-43-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.16.0-44-generic         System.map-3.16.0-37-generic
abi-3.16.0-45-generic         System.map-3.16.0-38-generic
abi-3.16.0-46-generic         System.map-3.16.0-39-generic
abi-3.16.0-48-generic         System.map-3.16.0-41-generic
abi-3.16.0-60-generic         System.map-3.16.0-43-generic
config-3.16.0-37-generic      System.map-3.16.0-44-generic
config-3.16.0-38-generic      System.map-3.16.0-45-generic
config-3.16.0-39-generic      System.map-3.16.0-46-generic
config-3.16.0-41-generic      System.map-3.16.0-48-generic
config-3.16.0-43-generic      System.map-3.16.0-60-generic
config-3.16.0-44-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-37-generic
config-3.16.0-45-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
config-3.16.0-46-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-39-generic
config-3.16.0-48-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-41-generic
config-3.16.0-60-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.16.0-44-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-41-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-45-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-44-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
```

I then ran:

```
Uname -a

Linux XVM48 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Nothing seems to be working.....
So I read other posts, and they said to remove old kernels, and I don't see any old versions. Also, I thought about expanding the /boot partition but I wasn't sure if that was a good idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're out of space.  All those 3.16.0-XX kernels except for the last one installed are obsolete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 2):

As per your logs - you are falling short of space in /boot. Find out your /boot disk usage and how much space is remaining by

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/# du -c -s -h /boot
193M    /boot
193M    total
```

And also purge old unused kernels by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

and manually installed kernels by

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

For more details, refer [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: `purge-old-kernels` is not installed.